# D’avance / en avance / à l’avance /l’avance

Tags: grammaire, sens, usage, prépositions

Le train arrive à Bordeaux tous les jours à 15h mais aujourd’hui il a un quart d’heure......
La réponse, c’est « d’avance ».
Je suis dans l'incertitude parce qu'on dit toujours « je suis arrivée en avance » (contraire de  « en retard »).
Pourquoi utilise -t-on « d’avance » dans ce cas ?

Comment: @Fólkvangr Cette question n'est pas hors sujet : il pourrait exister un principe sémantique ou grammatical peut-être, qui expliquerait la différence. Il me semble qu'il n'y en ait pas mais il faudrait savoir où chercher ; les tournures idiomatiques ne sont pas souvent portées dans les dictionnaires comme telles et dans le TLFi il faut être un usager habituel et se servir des couleurs qui indiquent la nature de nombreux éléments, comme par exemple les syntagmes.

Comment: @Fólkvangr En linguistique, le syntagme est un constituant syntaxique et sémantique de la phrase. On l'appelle aussi groupe ou entité car il est composé d'un ou plusieurs mots allant jusqu'à la phrase simple. Un syntagme peut être constitué de plusieurs autres, les sous-syntagmes, dont les formes indivisibles sont le nom, le mot composé ou la locution. 
Le syntagme est composé d'un noyau, appelé aussi « tête » (qui détermine sa nature et sa fonction) et d'éventuels satellites (ou subordonnés). 
Cinq types de syntagmes  : verbal, adverbial, adjectival, prépositionnel et nominal

Comment: @Fólkvangr Avez-vous oublié la question ?  — *…on dit toujours « je suis arrivée **en** avance » (contraire de « en retard »). Pourquoi utilise -t-on « **d**’avance » dans ce cas ?* — On aurait très bien pu dire « Ma montre a deux minutes en avance. » mais ce n'est pas ce qui a été choisi. La question est tout simplement « demander s'il n'y aurait pas un motif pour la différence ».

Comment: Je vote pour "pas hors sujet". Non, il ne suffit pas de consulter le dictionnaire pour apprendre le français. et dans ce cas, la question est justifiée.

Answer (score 6):

C'est parce que ce n'est pas le même verbe.

Vous pourriez tout à fait dire "mais aujourd'hui il est en avance d'un quart d'heure" qui rejoint la construction que vous connaissiez. En disant "il a un quart d'heure d'avance", la grammaire de la phrase est différente (avoir + complément). Cependant le sens est identique.

Edit

"à l'avance" et "par avance" ont un sens très voisin mais avec quelques subtilités :

"à l'avance" est plutôt utilisé pour une action. Ainsi on dira "le train arrive un quart d'heure à l'avance" et non "le train est un quart d'heure à l'avance" (on dirait "en avance d'un quart d'heure" dans ce cas-là, comme déjà vu).

De plus, "à l'avance" a en général une connotation d'action délibérée. On dira "j'étais en avance chez le médecin.", c'est neutre. On dira "je suis arrivé à l'avance chez le médecin", cela signifie que c'était volontaire de ma part d'arriver plus tôt. "à l'avance" signifie en général un but, parfois évident et implicite. "J'ai réservé à l'avance", bien sûr, veut dire qu'on a réservé plus tôt pour éviter qu'il n'y ait plus de place. (d'ailleurs c'est presque un pléonasme, si on réserve, c'est forcément à l'avance...)

Quant à "par avance" il n'est guère utilisé que pour les remerciements : "Je vous remercie par avance" signifie : "Je vous remercie dès maintenant, avant même que vous ayez agi pour mériter ce remerciement"

Comment: Merci  pourrais-je poser encore une question ? «  à l’avance » Est-ce que c’est pareil qu’en avance. Par exemple, Elle devra tout réserver à l’avance /en avance.

Comment: @Fólkvangr  Je crois que c’est la même chose. Ça dépend le sens des phrases. À l’avance-tôt-avant les autres?

Comment: @user16887 pour "à l'avance" voir mon edit

Comment: @user16887 j'ai édité mon edit... J'avais oublié une partie. à l'avance signifie en général que cette avance est voulue.

Comment: @Fólkvangr La question ne porte pas sur des subtilités grammaticales mais l'existence ou pas de subtilités dans les significations. Certes, "avance" est un déverbal de "avancer", et ça n'a aucune importance. "en avance d'un quart d'heure" et "un quart d'heure d'avance" ont le même sens, l'emploi de l'un ou l'autre étant piloté par la grammaire générale de la phrase, "à l'avance" et "par avance" ont une subtilité de sens, c'est tout ce qui importe.

Answer (score 0):

*La réponse est basée sur la définition du dictionnaire pour déterminer quel terme choisir parmi les termes proposés.*

Ces termes peuvent être caractérisés comme des collocations. Effectivement, certains sens sont exprimés en fonction d'un choix initial de mots (combinaison de mots potentiellement variable). [1]

[1] Le [TLFi](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/avance) indique que les termes « à l'avance », « d'avance », « par avance » ainsi que « en avance » sont des locutions adverbiales.

> Le train arrive à Bordeaux tous les jours à quinze heures mais aujourd'hui il **a un quart d'heure *d'avance***. *Avoir (un certain temps) d'avance*.

Le terme « en avance » est une locution adverbiale qui n'exprime pas explicitement la durée (ou qui n'évoque pas la durée) mais *l'avance manifeste* (adjectif) dans l'accomplissement d'une action (sens proche).

> Loc. adv. *En avance*. Avant le temps fixé ou prévu.

On ne peut pas employer le terme « en avance » dans la phrase citée pour exemple.

Answer (score -2):

La simple raison de cet usage est que l'on a affaire à un idiomatisme, comme le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avance) le stipule, un syntagme du langage.

> 1. P. anal. Fait de précéder quelqu'un ou quelque chose dans le temps.
>      **Avoir (un certain temps) d'avance (sur qqn ou qqc., pour qqc.)**; **avoir une avance de (indication de temps) sur qqn ou qqc.**

Comment: @Fólkvangr La raison est simple sans complication, il n'y a pas besoin de longue explication, une simple phrase suffit ! C'est tout ce que cela signifie. Le TLFi stipule la nature de cette expression au moyen d'une couleur. avoir affaire à (TLFi) Avec une idée de simple (pré)occupation ou d'intérêt : ce à quoi on s'intéresse. Par contre « idiome » n'est pas correct.

Comment: @Fólkvangr 1/  Le sens du mot comme enregistré dans le TLFi : « Ce qui rend compte d'un fait, d'un phénomène ». Je ne pourrais pas mieux expliquer ce mot. 2/ Bien sûr, on peut parfois arriver à une explication détaillée qui permet de savoir d'où provient une expression figée, mais souvent on ne trouve qu'une première trace dans un ouvrage ancien et rien de plus ; qu'il y ait donc accès à la « petite histoire » ou non on résume le tout en expliquant qu'il s'agit d'un idiomatisme. N'êtes-vous pas à peu près d'accord avec ça ?

Comment: Si le lecteur ne comprend pas ce qu'est un idiomatisme il peut utiliser un dictionnaire et finalement si le dictionnaire ne suffit pas, demander sur le FSE. Lui dire que c'est un idiomatisme n'est pas lui faire croire quoi que ce soit, c'est lui indiquer la catégorie de construction, qui  ainsi lui fait comprendre qu'il n'y a pas lieu de chercher dans la grammaire ou dans la sémantique pour des explications de première nécessité.